# Dashboard grid alternative

Tags: html, css

I am wondering, if there are any alternative/better ways to create this dashboard layout with flex or maybe grid?  So I wouldn't need to add this pusher with 200px margin.
I heard about that it can be done using `flex 1 1 0%` or something like that, I am not sure how to implement it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.body {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

.pusher {
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.nav{
  background: yellow;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="pusher">

</div>
<div class="body">
<div class="nav">
Nav
</div>
test
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at grid-template-areas, or more generally https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

Comment: @julien.giband even with this grid when I set fixed position for menu, I will need to add aswell this pusher div..

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go...**

I removed the div with `class="pusher"` and changed/added the CSS as follows:

```
.sidebar {
  width: 20vw;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  right: 0;
}
```

Basically, I made the div `class="sidebar"` and the div with `class="body"` make up to 100 % of the screen but **in different relative units, i.e. vw** (20 vw + 80 vw = 100 vw). So, now I just needed to add `right: 0;` to the div with `class="body"` in order to achieve the exact same result as you did with `margin-right: 200px;`. I also added `position: absolute;` to the div with `class="body"`, otherwise it won't work.

See the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 20vw;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80vw;
  right: 0;
}

.nav {
  background: yellow;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="sidebar"></div>

  <div class="body">
    <div class="nav">Nav</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I change your HTML and CSS code and I do my best for you.

HTML CODE:

```
  <div class="main">

    <div class="sidebar">This is Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="nav">
        Nav
        </div>
    <div class="content-body">
    test
    </div>
  </div>
    
  </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main{
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;

}

.nav{
  background: yellow;
  height: 60px;
}
.content-body {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
```